# How to wrap each function in project?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have tons of functions in my WinForms project and i'm using NLog for logging. I want to have an ability to wrap each function with `nlogger.Info("start")` and `nlogger.Info("end")` so i will know in which place actual exception occurred or where the code currently runs.

Is there a smart way to do it or i will need to place lines from above in all of my functions ?

Comment: The stack-trace will tell you where an exception happens... Just sayin'

Comment: You right but some of exceptions are without full stack and there are exceptions without stack at all. Moreover if some function is called twice during the run you wouldn't know which run caused an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) can do this for you, and can apply at the assembly level (via assembly-level attributes). However, I would be cautious of the potential performance impact. Writing the "aspect" should be pretty minimal.

Comment: Even you can do it for the external assemblies where you dont have source code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196865/postsharp-on-assemblies-i-dont-have-source-for

Answer (score 2):

Ifyou don't want to do it manually - you could consider Aspect Oriented Programming.

To summarise what it is, it matches functions which run and offers 'advice' before, after or around. So you can easily make one which runs at all functions and adds to the log. Never used it for C# but I used it for Java.

You can find a class for .NET. Read this for more info:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/