# PostSharp - Apply aspect across assemblies

Tags: postsharp

I have several projects and wish to apply aspects across multiple projects. I use the multicast attribute like so:

```
[assembly:MyProject.Aspects.NotifiableObject(
    AttributeTargetAssemblies = "MyProject.Entities",
    AttributeTargetTypes = "MyProject.Entities.*")]
```

This is placed in a AspectInfo.cs file inside my main project. This approach however does not seem to work. The entities inside `MyProject.Entities` do not recieve the NotifiableObject aspect. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196865/postsharp-on-assemblies-i-dont-have-source-for), but that did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. You have to add Postsharp to each project.